# Should I be using two dictionaries or is there a better way?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a new file based on a JamBarcode which looks up the Price from JamPrice and the rest of the information from JamDetails and puts it into a new file.

I've got (at the moment) two dictionaries like the following:

```
JamPrice = {
"JamBarcode": "1234", "Price": "1",
} print JamPrice
```

and

```
JamDetails = {
"JamBarcode": "1234", "Colour": "red", "Size": "small"
} print JamDetails
```

Is this the right data structure to be using, and am I going about it the right way or is there a much easier way to do it? I've been looking at  http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/how-to-use-dictionaries-in-python to help.

Comment: What? What's a *"JamBarcode"*. Your code doesn't seem to be **actually doing anything**, so... going about *what* the right way? Why don't you press on and see how it goes?

Comment: why not keep the price information in the `JamDetails` dictionary?

Comment: @PaulH:  My guess is that details are for the immutable attributes whereas price can vary.

Comment: This is not proper python syntax. You close a dictionary on the same line as a print statement without interposing the two statements with a semicolon.

Comment: What is "right" would depend in part on what you want to *do* with it, which you have not disclosed.

Comment: Why not do `barcode_to_price = {'1234': '1', '5678': '2'}`?

Comment: @Kyrubas:  True.  I'm just trying to explain why someone might think of them as separate.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, I'd separate these into two tables in a database: product info, and product *retail* info. The latter should contain all the info necessary to *sell* the item, which in addition to retail price is probably going to be something like which department to count it under, how many units are sold, any restrictions on the product (is it alcohol? Do you need to age-verify the sale?)

The latter should also contain a foreignkey to point back to the former, or in the case of a dictionary should contain some matching information (e.g. barcode, like you have).

Comment: Now we're getting away from Python... I'm not sure this is directly related to OP's question.

Comment: Frankly, OP's question is getting away from Python, too! "How do I arrange this data structure" is only *probably* on-topic

Answer (score 1):

I think you need two data: `products` and `prices`

These are linked by the barcode. Then they can vary independently:

```
products = {
    "1234": dict(name="jam", colour="red", size="small")
    "5678": dict(name="marmalade", colour="orange", size="medium")
}
prices = {
    "1234": "1.5",
    "5678": "1.75"
}
```

Comment: The only concern here is if there's more than one way to sell the item (at a different price) using the same barcode. We see this all the time with single cans of beer versus six packs of beer. Usually they're rang up with the same barcode, but of course have vastly different prices.

Comment: @AdamSmith Indeed, but that's beyond this question. See [Code Kata01: Supermarket Pricing](http://codekata.com/kata/kata01-supermarket-pricing/).

Comment: Agreed, but something that should be kept in mind! I work I.T. for a grocery chain, so this is very much in my wheelhouse :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest combining all the jam details into a unified dictionary, and accessing the contents using your JamBarcode. In other words, there is effectively an object associated with each barcode key inside the dictionary.

e.g.

```
# create a dictionary called jam:
jam_dictionary = {}

# insert items into your dictionary using index notation:
jam_dictionary['1234'] = {'Colour': 'red', 'Size': 'small', 'Price': '1'}

# you can also use the index key to retrieve the information
print(jam_dictionary['1234'])
# {'Colour': 'red', 'Size': 'small', 'Price': '1'}

# and specific sub-fields
print(jam_dictionary['1234']['Colour'])
# red

jam_dictionary['1234']['Colour'] = 'blue'
print(jam_dictionary['1234']['Colour'])
# blue
```

You can also construct your dictionary like this:

```
jam_dictionary = {
    '1234': {'Colour': 'red', 'Size':'small', 'Price': '1'},
    '5678': {'Colour': 'blue', 'etc':'etc'}
}
```

But this is more convoluted and since you'll likely add or remove things after the dictionary is already created, you may as well do it the first way.

If you would benefit from having associated functions for handling or processing the data, then you should start thinking about possibly creating a Jam Class

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you really want a collection of Jams and that you are using the barcode information to keep track of which one you are specifically referencing.

It looks to me like you would have a dict:

```
Jams = { '1234':[1, "red", "small"]}
```

you could then add more jams to the dict using the barcode as the key.

You are not far enough in the book to "get" this but you will find that keeping the information in the list "right"_will get tricky and you will want to use a "named tuple" instead

```
import collections
JamTuple = collections.namedtuple('Jam', ['barcode', 'price', 'color', 'size'])
a_jam = JamTiuple(1234, price=1,color='red', size='Small')
JamsDict = {1234:a_jam}
```

But really, it depends a lot on what you want to do next.

Comment: I like `namedtuple` here, but it's introducing some concepts that aren't really appropriate for someone brand new to Python.